# Additional meanings of 也

Tags: meaning, usage

I am reading this example:

听众至少也有五千人。
The audience was not less than five thousand.

Dictionary gives only "also, too" meanings for 也 and it doesn't seem to fit in this example. So what is the role of this word here?

Comment: see previous Q，esp. quotation from ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂contained in comment #1 https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/what-does-%e4%b9%9f-mean-in-this-sentence  (besides, most users look at more than one dictionary, bkrs & jukuu are recommended)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is used to emphasize the verb 有.

We can omit 也 and show the same meaning.
听众至少(也)有五千人。

[也 [副] 3](http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000010776)
表示强调。如：“一点也不”、“再也不敢”、“连爸妈也乐得开怀大笑。”

[也 yě 〈副〉(5)](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/zidian/_4E5F.html)
 表示强调 [even]。如: 也须 (也应当; 也应该); 连老人也干活