# Is it ok to omit "也" in responce 我也很好?

Tags: grammar

Is it ok to omit "也" in responce 我也很好?

Dialog (3rd line):

-- 你好吗?

-- [ **我** ] 很好! 你好吗?

-- 我 [ **也** ] 很好!

And if it is ok to omit 也 in third line, is it ok to add 我 in the second line?

Comment: 也 often left untranslated in English, cf. ＂汉语８００虚词用法词典＂也７。表示委婉 used in a euphemistic statement, comment #1 of https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/20906/what-does-%e4%b9%9f-mean-in-this-sentence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seriously I think people only say 我也很好 when the situation is a bit awkward.

It's like adding to the meaninglessness of your answer by stressing the similarity to another one's meaningless answer.

actually when you ask 你好吗 in Chinese it already starts to get awkward. At least you can ask more specifically e.g. 最近怎么样？ (how're u doing lately?) than asking a question which neither contains any information nor fits language convention.

Comment: =))))) if 你好吗? is meaningless and awkward, do you mean that e.g. CEO or bank VP would say 吃反了吗?  to his/her colleagues in China?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko The dialog you provided seems very awkward to me. Actually I ve never get into or heard of such a dialog...

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko 吃饭了吗 is often used between friends, neighbors, colleagues under informal circumstance, and note that it usually happens not long after meal time (it sounds a bit silly otherwise)

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko In fact I suspect that the dialog is the translation of "How are you Fine and you" platitude LOL. It's not authentic at all.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko well if you want a business or formal tone, you can say 别来无恙 (I hope nothing bad happened since we last met) or just 你好. What I meant is mostly that in Chinese "how are you" hasn't become just a greeting, people will actually think for a few seconds to answer you. And when thinking, they'll feel the ambiguity that you might not be really asking then there's awkwardness.

Comment: When I actually think about it, there's no commonly-used phrase that's longer than hi/你好 and shorter than literally asking/caring about others' situation. I guess it's just a cultural difference.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko In business occasions, between acquaintances ppl just say 早/早上好(Morning/Good Morning) or similar for meaningless greetings. Between strangers, 你好 is formal enough and should be replied by 你好.

Comment: *"when you ask 你好吗？ in Chinese it already starts to get awkward"* but is *"你好！"*  makes you feel awkward? I saw lots of native Chinese videos with *"大家好！"，”老师好！“*, actually never heard *"你好！", "你们好！"*

Answer (score 2):

If you omit 也, the result is like this:

- How are you?
- Fine! And you?
- Fine!

but if you use 也, the dialog is like:

- How are you?
- Fine! And you?
- I'm fine too!

Both are grammatically correct, but I don't know what is more *appropriate* in chinese, although in my lessons and in my mother language (italian) we usually talk like the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The word 也 can be direct translated into English word "too", the way of using it in the sentence is basically the same as well.

Having 也 in your sentence basically just add in a "too"

我很好    <---> I'm fine

我也很好  <---> I'm fine too